# Updating a variable in Python Schedule

Tags: python, schedule

With the python schedule, I am unable to feed the updated output back to the variable. Is there a smart way to achieve this?

```
x = 10

from schedule import every, repeat, run_pending
import time

@repeat(every(3).seconds, x)
def yee(x):
    x = x * 2
    print(x)
    return x

while x != 80:
    run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Currently I am getting output like this:

```
20
20
20
```

But I am hoping to get output like this:

```
20
40
80
```

Comment: You need to assign to the global variable, not a local variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update a global, then you have to use the `global` statement.  Right now, you set the global `x` once (to 10).  The name `x` within your function is entirely local.  And there's no point in returning anything.

```
@repeat(every(3).seconds)
def yee():
    global x
    x *= 2
    print(x)
```

Comment: You are simply an awesome human being, Tim. Thank you